# How to specify units in output layer in tf.keras?

Tags: tf.keras

The shape of a single input and output is 15 x 61 in my dataset. I'm specifying input_shape=(15,61). That means mapping between 15 x 61 to 15 x 61 and it is not a classification problem. What should be the units specification in the output layer?

```
model = tf.keras.models.Sequential([tf.keras.layers.Dense(units=128,input_shape =(15,61),
tf.keras.layers.Dense(units=128, activation=tf.nn.relu),
tf.keras.layers.Dense(units=, activation=tf.nn.softmax)])
```

Comment: Can you confirm in how many classes you want to classify? I answered and I can complete my answer if you provide more information about your goal.

Answer (score 1):

You have all the information in the [Keras turorial on Dense](https://keras.io/layers/core/). If you wish to do classification, the output shape must be the number of classes. 
If you wish a 15 * 61 as an input and 15*61 as output, just flatten all that : `15 x 61 = 915`, so take a 915 size layer and output a 915 size layer, then reshape it in order to have the initial shape.

Comment: My mapping is 15x61 to 15x61

Comment: You mean 15 features and 61 samples, in the input ? And also 61 output size in the end ? You have a neural network, you do not have convolutions here, you do not parse images, do we agree about that ?

Comment: The single input data point is 15 x 61
and the single output data is 15 X 61

Comment: Ok then why don't you flatten that, you obtain a 915 (15 x 61) size layer and the output with the same size ? Then, you can reshape in order to obtain the initial 2D size.